# Absolute panel collision with r shiny dashboard sidebar panel

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm trying to add `absolutePanel` to my shiny dashboard app. I want the panel to be at the bottom of the page with the width of the window and adjust to it when the sidebar is visible or not. The problem is that when the sidebar is opened some of the panel is not visible:

[image: left part of the panel not visible]

On the other hand if I set the width from the left side of a panel and close the sidebar it's far from the left end of the window:

[image: panel too short]

Here is a reproducible code:

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    absolutePanel(
      bottom = 0, left = 0, right = 0, # or left = 300
      fixed = TRUE,
      wellPanel(
        style = "padding: 8px; border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC; background: #FFFFEE;",
        HTML("Save changes?"),
        actionButton("save", "Save"),
        actionButton("cancel", "Cancel")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try removing `absolutePanel` with `div` that it produces with added high enough `z-index` to style:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    div(
      style = "left:0px; right:0px; bottom:0px; position:fixed; cursor:inherit; z-index: 10000;",
      wellPanel(
        style = "padding: 8px; border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC; background: #FFFFEE;",
        HTML("Save changes?"),
        actionButton("save", "Save"),
        actionButton("cancel", "Cancel")
      ) 
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Remove `position:fixed;` to make it adjustable to screen size with/out sidebar panel jus as regular body content.